# 2 function run in one activity

Tags: android

May i know how to run two function in one activity
example c->b->a

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, null, jpegCallBack);
public void sendemail(){
public void performDial(){
```

this all functions are inside one activity

Kindly assist  me thanks

Comment: This is vague. Do you want to start multiple Intents in a specified Activity?

Comment: Please post your idea properly. Technically you can run as many functions as you want. Just run 'em

Comment: yes,i wan start multiple intent in one activity

Comment: my logic is like this after camera take picture ,the app will proceed to send an email after that will make a call to user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your camera and take picture with this

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
URI pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(<path where you want to save your file>));
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
startActivityForResult(camera);
```

After that `onActivityResult`,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT){
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            sendEmail(Uri.parse(data.toURI()));
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}

private void sendEmail(Uri path){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"me@me.com"}); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Default Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Default Text"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
}
```

Comment: Good job. I was just typing this up!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036413/email-not-sent-on-my-app#comment19483947_14036413 how can i manage the intent and apply to my code

Comment: You literally are making us write code for you.. The above explanation is comprehensive and good. Don't rely on us to write your whole app